# What will happen if I pass 0 to random.nextInt()

Tags: java

I am using java.util.random's nextInt function to get a random number, and I noticed that my code could possibly pass a 0 to the function.  I am wondering what the result would be in this case.  I am guessing it would simply return 0 every time, but I am not sure.

Comment: You could always try it, or look at the source...

Comment: Downvote because it would be simple to test yourself. If you didn't understand the results you could then post them and ask why they are that way.

Answer (score 5):

It will throw runtime exception if you pass `n = 0`.

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if you pass in zero.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

> **Parameters:**
>   `n` - the bound on the random number to be returned. **Must be positive.**
>   **Returns:**
>   the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive) from this random number generator's sequence
>   **Throws:**
>   `IllegalArgumentException` - if `n` is not positive